# Problema con aplicacion typeorm

Tags: mysql, nodejs, typescript, typeorm

buenos días tengo un problema con aplicación typeorm.
Aplicación: (Node, Mysql, typeorm, typescript).
Estoy siguiendo un tutorial para usar typeorm, sin embargo tengo un problema cuando ejecuto la aplicación, el video que estoy siguiendo es este https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8si7IFlj0l4&list=PL_9MDdjVuFjHtNjQV2Kvs1xJIazMCH3Pi&index=1&t=825s, el problema surge a los 13:50 minutos.

```
import { getRepository } from "typeorm"
import { NextFunction, Request, Response } from "express" import { User } from "../entity/User"

export class UserController {

private userRepository = getRepository(User)

async all(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return this.userRepository.find()
}

async one(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return this.userRepository.findOne(request.params.id)
}

async save(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return this.userRepository.save(request.body)
}

async remove(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    let userToRemove = await this.userRepository.findOneBy({ id: request.params.id })
    await this.userRepository.remove(userToRemove)
}
}
```

Acá me sale error en :

```
import { getRepository } from "typeorm"
private userRepository = getRepository(User)
```

Me sale este error: Gets repository for the given entity class. @deprecated

```
    async one(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    return this.userRepository.findOne(request.params.id)
}
    async remove(request: Request, response: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    let userToRemove = await this.userRepository.findOneBy({ id: request.params.id })
    await this.userRepository.remove(userToRemove)
}

El tipo "string" no tiene propiedades en común con el tipo "FindOneOptions".ts(2559)
```

Tengo 2 fomras de ejecutarlo:

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "ts-node src/index.ts",
  "typeorm": "typeorm-ts-node-commonjs",
  "tsc": "tsc",
  "dev": "set debug=* && ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only ./src/index.ts"
} }
```

Con npm start me sale este error:

```
    TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
src/controller/UserController.ts:14:44 - error TS2559: Type 'string' has no properties in common with type 'FindOneOptions<User>'.

14         return this.userRepository.findOne(request.params.id)
                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src/controller/UserController.ts:22:66 - error TS2322: Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | FindOperator<number>'.

22         let userToRemove = await this.userRepository.findOneBy({ id: request.params.id })
```

Con npm run dev me sale este error:

```
ConnectionNotFoundError: Connection "default" was not found.
at ConnectionManager.get (C:\Users\braya\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\Dreams\dreams\src\connection\ConnectionManager.ts:43:32)
at getRepository (C:\Users\braya\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\Dreams\dreams\src\globals.ts:183:10)
at new UserController (C:\Users\braya\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\Dreams\dreams\src\controller\UserController.ts:7:43)
at C:\Users\braya\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\Dreams\dreams\src\index.ts:17:29
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\braya\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\Dreams\dreams\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\braya\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\Dreams\dreams\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\braya\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\Dreams\dreams\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\braya\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\Dreams\dreams\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\braya\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\Dreams\dreams\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\braya\OneDrive\Documentos\Proyectos\Dreams\dreams\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
```

Gracias por la atención prestada espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de TypeORM está usando?. Por ejemplo, desde la versión `0.3.0` la firma `findOne(id)` fue eliminada.

Comment: @wchiquito la versión que estoy usando es esta "typeorm": "0.3.9",

Comment: En ese caso intente cambiar: `userRepository.findOne(request.params.id)` a `userRepository.findOneBy({ id: request.params.id })`.

Comment: Me sale este error
La propiedad "findOneBy" no existe en el tipo "Repository<User>". ¿Quería decir "findOne"?ts(2551)
Repository.d.ts(235, 6): "findOne" se declara aquí.

Este es el repositorio
 findOne(id?: string | number | Date | ObjectID, options?: FindOneOptions<Entity>): Promise<Entity | undefined>;

Comment: Verifique en el fichero `node_modules/typeorm/repository/Repository.d.ts` si existe la firma `findOneBy`.

Comment: No, solo exiten : 
findOne
findOneOrFail

Comment: Parece tener un problema con las versiones instaladas. En principio la versión `0.3.9` de TypeORM dispone de la firma [findOneBy()](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/0.3.9/src/repository/Repository.ts#L536).